# Сохранение в бинарный файл с помощью PHP

Tags: php

Ребята, а можно ли в php сохранять бинарные файлы (Random access files)? Если да, то как?
Спасибо=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, хм общий ответ - да, можно, но работа с ними может оказаться сложнее, чем в сях/дельфях, например. Надо отдельно заморачиваться с вычислением размера, еще недавно напоролся на то, что иногда перегружают стандартные функции работы со строками на мультибайтовые инструменты и получается так:

```
echo strlen(chr(0).chr(32)); // 1 o_O
```

В общем случае придется создавать объект с методами записи/чтения. Минимальный пример:

```
class MyRecord {
private $prop1 = 0; // long
private $prop2 = 0; // byte
private $prop3 = 0; // int16 aka short
function write($handler) {
  return fwrite($handler, pack('LCS', $this->prop1,$this->prop2,$this->prop3));
  }
function read($n, $handler) { // $n = [0..]
  $size = 7; // long + byte + short
  fseek($handler, $n * $size);
  if (feof($handler)) return false;
  $packed = fread($handler, $size);
  list($this->prop1, $this->prop2, $this->prop3) = array_values(unpack('Lv1/Cv2/Sv3', $packed));
  return true;
  }
function __construct($n = null, $handler = null) {
  if (!is_null($n) && !is_null($handler))
    $this->read($n, $handler);
  }
}
// ну и потестим)
$f = fopen('text.txt', 'rb');
$rec1 = new MyRecord(0, $f);
$rec2 = new MyRecord(1, $f);
var_dump($rec1, $rec2);
fclose($f);
```

Для справки идем на php.net и читаем про функции pack, unpack, ну и мобыть еще что-то непонятно было.

Да, если хотите работать со строками - запишите на всякий случай полезность

```
function bl($string) { //  ByteLength
  if (ini_get('mbstring.func_overload'))
    return mb_strlen($string, '8bit');
  return strlen($string);
  }
```